# AWS Amplify `configure` has no options

Tags: expo, aws-amplify

I have been following this tutorial: https://blog.expo.io/how-to-build-cloud-powered-mobile-apps-with-expo-aws-amplify-2fddc898f9a2  The steps are extremely similar to the ones that I previously followed with Amplify's own documentation. But I'm getting stopped right at the start.

When I run `amplify configure`, it prompts me for the backend providers, but doesn't have any options available there. I then have to ctrl-C to get out. So the whole log looks like this:

```
    amplify configure  
   ? Select the backend providers. 

   Done in 2.29s.
```

I get a very similar problem when running `amplify init`.  So the result is that I'm totally dead in the water with AWS Amplify, before even getting started. Anyone out there have any clue why I don't have any options in the menu prompts, or how to get around them?

Comment: Having the same problem. `amplify configure` doesn't give me any options. It just quits if I press enter.

Comment: Yup. I'm continuing to have this problem. Just gave up on Amplify and moved on with life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue myself. A solution to this will be to reinstall the amplify cli using the following yarn command:

> `yarn global add @aws-amplify/cli`

Hope that helps!

> Source:
>   https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/2410#issuecomment-535236409